# Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, robolectric-gradle-plugin

When updating to gradle plugin 1.1.0 I kept getting the following error

```
Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists
```

I am also using the Robolectric gradle plugin from [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin), v0.14.0.

The new gradle 1.1.0 plugin adds additional unit test support, so I suspect the gradle and Robolectric plugins are battling for use of 'testCompile,' though I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the fine people over at Robolectric have updated their plugin to resolve the issue.

Use [Robolectric Plugin v1.0.0](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/releases/tag/1.0.0) and you will be able to update gradle plugin and also run your Robolectric tests.

Here is the discussion on the pull request if you are interested in further information:

https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/128

Answer (score 8):

To fix that issue i did the following:

Added the following to my build gradle script:

```
 apply plugin: 'org.robolectric'

 dependencies {
    classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:1.0.0'
 }
```

This wouldnt work for me with gradle version 1.1.0 though. I had to use 1.1.0-rci which is still only in experimental phase.
So i added the following to my project build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0-rc1'
}
```

Ran sync project with gradle files and the issue was corrected. Hope this helps.

Comment: the `-rc-1` is no longer needed, at the time of writing this, gradle version is `1.1.3`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it.

In my case I had my

apply:plugin statements below the configurations I have added them above and the already exists issue is fixed.