# ConnectSDK - Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle, live-connect-sdk

I'm trying to download connnectSDK-lite for android and when I sync gradle I come up with this error:

Error:(18, 0) Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists.

I've done some digging and the problem seems to be with the unit test framework roboelectric that connectSDK uses.

[Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729576/cannot-add-a-configuration-with-name-testcompile-as-a-configuration-with-that)

I checked out this post and tried messing around with connectSDK's build.gradle to see if I could fix anything, but haven't had any success. I was hoping you guys might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I have the exact same error at the moment.