# ERROR: 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

When I am trying to setup existing Android project I'm getting this error:

> Error:(15, 0) Cannot add a configuration with name 'testCompile' as a configuration with that name already exists

Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729576/cannot-add-a-configuration-with-name-testcompile-as-a-configuration-with-that